# Less file not working with html

Tags: html, css, less, livereload, macrabbit-espresso

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Coming Soon</title>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="author" content="" />

<!--mobile specific meta-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>

<!-- css goes here -->
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="styles.less">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.1/less.min.js"></script>

<script> less = { env: "development", async: false, fileAsync: true }; </script>


<!--[if lt ie 9]-->
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<!--[endif]-->

<!--Js-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="Js/countdown.js"></script>

<script>


<!--less javascript-->
<script src="http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- live reload -->
<script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')</script>

</head>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the code in my html, my less file doesnt change no matter what code i use, im using espresso and livereload to compile my code, i have also changed the language so i can edit the less file in espresso while using the css highlights etc.

I've tried so many things and as im new to web Design and coding this is quite hard for me, im trying to build a coming soon page which im nearly done with but all these problems keep coming up.

Comment: And "by not working" you mean what exactly? Well, your Less including lines  after `<!-- css goes here -->` appear to be correct (except that `<script> less = {` should go before `less.js` script link). (What is definitely not correct is that you also included another `less.js` in `<!--less javascript-->`, though this should not harm since that link is not valid for a years by now).

Comment: Now assuming your HTML is actually an empty page, yet again how do you now it's working or not? "my less file doesnt change no matter what code i use" - your Less file should not change itself, it's *you* who writes the code in that Less file to be translated to CSS.

Comment: Right the code in the middle is not in this post as its long, and doesn't change anything, the less file i have doesn't change anything to the website when i look at it through livereload which is meant to compile the files together.

Comment: So how are we I supposed to help if we can know neither what Less/CSS you use nor what HTML it is applied to? (Well, either way: fix your Less options and redundant `less.js` link I mentioned in my first comment. Then the rest is a matter of you working with browser development tools - look in console for errors/warnings, check if CSS styles exist and apply to HTML, etc etc. Then when you'll find a particular error - create a question for that particular problem. Just "not working", "not applying", "not loading" are generally useless and won't produce anything but useless guesswork comments.

Comment: Okay i have moved the <script> less ={ above the less.js file, i also have removed the other less.js file at the bottom of the body. with the html i have created a header, content, footer etc all the code in the body is working as its showing up on the localhost. for the less code i have used

Comment: // VARIABLES

link: #2a9ccc;
dark-link: darken(@link, 10%);
base-text: #1f2225;
light-text: #909091;
light-border: #dcdee0;
light-bg: #f7f7f7;

// PARAMETRIC MIXINS
.round (radius: 5px) {
 -webkit-border-radius: radius;
 border-radius: radius; this is some of the code i have used in the less code etc. .round (radius: 5px) {
 -webkit-border-radius: radius;
 border-radius: radius;
}

Comment: sorry for not being about to copy the link right im new to this website.